# How to change primary profile?

Tags: linkedin

I am unsure how to change the primary profile on LinkedIn.

In my case below, I'd like to change my default profile to English.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an available option :

[image]

> Creating or Deleting a Profile in Another Language
>   You can create your profile in a language that is different from your default profile. **While you can't change the language of your primary profile,** you can create as many additional language profiles from the options available.
>
> Having multiple language profiles makes it easier for other members and recruiters to find you.

[Source : linkedin.com/help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1717/creating-or-deleting-a-profile-in-another-language?lang=en)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with an [edit] that reflects the current functionality.  As it stands this is the accepted answer but is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2022, this is now possible. Simply follow these steps:

1. Backup all the text of your profile sections in all the languages, you might follow the instructions I gave below in this same article but just copy the texts somewhere (like on a text file, a note, a pastebin or whatever suits you better)
2. Delete any secondary language you added to your LinkedIn profile
3. Add the language that used to be primary language as second language and select English (or whatever you want to be your main language) when it asks what language is your existing profile written in.

More information can be found under:
https://phaberest.medium.com/how-you-can-change-your-linkedin-profile-default-language-d37a5109b358

Comment: Thank you, @cvaz

Comment: 3. Looks like now you can simply choose to make your new profile primary when creating it, there is a toggle. (Also it remembers the remaining profile language after step 2 and doesn't ask when creating another profile.)

Comment: Ah, actually you can just switch the primary language profile now, no need to delete anything. It's in the dialog that's opened by the pencil icon near the "Profile language" panel.

Answer (score 1):

Open your profile, on the top right part where you can see the display language, you can click on the pencil icon, then you can stablish the default language or include a new one.
[image]